# CORBA Client/Server application, getting info from server (null values)

Tags: java, c++, corba, omniorb

I created a simple application in Java and C++ in CORBA, client-server app, take a look:

```
interface Task
{
    string getThingToDo();
};

#include "Task.idl"

interface Employee
{
    typedef sequence <Task> tasks;
    string getLastname();
    Task getTask(in short id);
};

#include "Employee.idl"

interface Work
{
    Employee getEmployee(in short id);
};
```

**TaskImpl.h** and **TaskImpl.cpp:**

```
#include "Task.hh"

class TaskImpl : public POA_Task
{
    private:
        CORBA::String_var thingToDo;

    public:
        TaskImpl(const char* thingToDo);
        char* getThingToDo();
};

#include "TaskImpl.h"

TaskImpl::TaskImpl(const char* thingToDo)
{
    this->thingToDo = CORBA::string_dup(thingToDo);
}

char* TaskImpl::getThingToDo()
{
    return CORBA::string_dup(this->thingToDo.in());
}
```

**EmployeeImpl.h** and **EmployeeImpl.cpp:**

```
#include "Employee.hh"
#include "TaskImpl.h"

class EmployeeImpl : public POA_Employee
{
    private:
        CORBA::String_var lastname;
        int id;
        Employee::tasks thingsToDo;

    public:
        EmployeeImpl(const char* lastname, int id);
        char* getLastname();
        Task_ptr getTask(::CORBA::Short id);
};

#include "EmployeeImpl.h"

EmployeeImpl::EmployeeImpl(const char* lastname, int id)
{
    this->lastname = CORBA::string_dup(lastname);
    this->id = id;
    this->thingsToDo.length(3);

    TaskImpl *t1, *t2, *t3;
    t1 = new TaskImpl("Print all the documents");
    t2 = new TaskImpl("Write the report");
    t3 = new TaskImpl("Make backup");

    this->thingsToDo[0] = t1->_this();
    this->thingsToDo[1] = t2->_this();
    this->thingsToDo[2] = t3->_this();
}

char* EmployeeImpl::getLastname()
{
    return CORBA::string_dup(this->lastname.in());
}

Task_ptr EmployeeImpl::getTask(::CORBA::Short id)
{
    return Task::_duplicate(this->thingsToDo[id-1]);
}
```

**WorkImpl.h** and **WorkImpl.cpp:**

```
#include "Work.hh"
#include <vector>
#include "EmployeeImpl.h"
using namespace std;

class WorkImpl : public POA_Work
{
    private:
        vector<EmployeeImpl> employees;

    public:
        WorkImpl();
        Employee_ptr getEmployee(::CORBA::Short id);
};
#include "WorkImpl.h"

 WorkImpl::WorkImpl()
 {
    EmployeeImpl ei1(CORBA::string_dup("Doe"), 1);
    EmployeeImpl ei2(CORBA::string_dup("Smith"), 2);
    EmployeeImpl ei3(CORBA::string_dup("Brown"), 3);

    employees.push_back(ei1);
    employees.push_back(ei2);
    employees.push_back(ei3);
 }

Employee_ptr WorkImpl::getEmployee(::CORBA::Short id)
{
    return employees[id]._this();
}
```

**Server.cpp:**

```
#include "WorkImpl.h"
#include <omniORB4/CORBA.h>
#include <omniORB4/Naming.hh>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 try
 {
  CORBA::ORB_ptr serverORB = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);

  CORBA::Object_var myPOAObj = serverORB->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");

  PortableServer::POA_var myPOA = PortableServer::POA::_narrow(myPOAObj);
  PortableServer::POAManager_var myManager = myPOA->the_POAManager();
  myManager->activate();

  WorkImpl *work = new WorkImpl();

  try
  {
   CORBA::Object_var nameServiceObj = serverORB->resolve_initial_references("NameService");

   if(!CORBA::is_nil(nameServiceObj))
   {
    CosNaming::NamingContext_ptr namingContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(nameServiceObj);
    CosNaming::Name serviceName;
    serviceName.length(1);
    serviceName[0].id = CORBA::string_dup("WorkService");
    namingContext->rebind(serviceName, work->_this());
    cout << "WorkService is running ...\n";
   }

  }catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound&){
      cerr << "CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound\n";
  }catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::InvalidName&){
      cerr << "CosNaming::NamingContext::InvalidName\n";
  }catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::CannotProceed&){
      cerr << "CosNaming::NamingContext::CannotProceed\n";
  }

  serverORB->run();

  delete work;
  serverORB->destroy();

  }catch(CORBA::SystemException&){
    cerr << "Caught CORBA::SystemException\n";
  }catch(CORBA::Exception&){
    cerr << "Caught CORBA::Exception  \n";
  }catch(omniORB::fatalException &fe){
    cerr << "Caught omniORB::fatalException\n";
    cerr << "File: " << fe.file() << "\n";
    cerr << "Line: " << fe.line() << "\n";
    cerr << "Msg: " << fe.errmsg() << "\n";
  }catch(...){
    cerr << "Caught unknown exception\n";
  }

   return 0;
}
```

**Client.java:**

```
package OtherPackage;

import java.util.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.*;
import org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.*;
import org.omg.CORBA.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
     try
     {
        org.omg.CORBA.ORB clientORB = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, null);

        if (clientORB == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem while creating ORB");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = clientORB.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

        Work work = WorkHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve_str("WorkService"));
        Employee e = work.getEmployee((short)1);
        System.out.println(e.getLastname());
        Task t = e.getTask((short)1);
        System.out.println(t.getThingToDo());

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
            }
    }
}
```

When I had **EmployeeImpl.cpp** like this:

```
#include "EmployeeImpl.h"

EmployeeImpl::EmployeeImpl(const char* lastname, int id)
{
    this->lastname = CORBA::string_dup(lastname);
    this->id = id;
    this->thingsToDo.length(3);

    TaskImpl *t1, *t2, *t3;
    t1 = new TaskImpl("Print all the documents");
    t2 = new TaskImpl("Write the report");
    t3 = new TaskImpl("Make backup");

    this->thingsToDo[0] = Task::_duplicate(t1->_this());
    this->thingsToDo[1] = Task::_duplicate(t2->_this());
    this->thingsToDo[2] = Task::_duplicate(t3->_this());
}

char* EmployeeImpl::getLastname()
{
    return CORBA::string_dup(this->lastname.in());
}

Task_ptr EmployeeImpl::getTask(::CORBA::Short id)
{
    return this->thingsToDo[id-1]._retn();
}
```

and I ran client fisrt time, I saw:

```
Smith
Print all the documents
```

which is correct. But when I ran my client for the second (and third, and so on ...) time, I saw:

```
Smith
null
```

where's the problem? I've been thinking about it a lot and wrote **EmployeeImpl.cpp** again:

```
#include "EmployeeImpl.h"

EmployeeImpl::EmployeeImpl(const char* lastname, int id)
{
    this->lastname = CORBA::string_dup(lastname);
    this->id = id;
    this->thingsToDo.length(3);

    TaskImpl *t1, *t2, *t3;
    t1 = new TaskImpl("Print all the documents");
    t2 = new TaskImpl("Write the report");
    t3 = new TaskImpl("Make backup");

    this->thingsToDo[0] = t1->_this();
    this->thingsToDo[1] = t2->_this();
    this->thingsToDo[2] = t3->_this();
}

char* EmployeeImpl::getLastname()
{
    return CORBA::string_dup(this->lastname.in());
}

Task_ptr EmployeeImpl::getTask(::CORBA::Short id)
{
    return Task::_duplicate(this->thingsToDo[id-1]);
}
```

and it all seems good now, every time I run client. But I'm not sure if it's good in CORBA way. Any suggestions?

Use those commands to compile and run server and client files (I use omniORB 4.1.6 and default-jdk package on Kubuntu 12.04):

```
Compile (and run) server files (just copy and paste):

g++ -c *.cpp -I$OMNIORB_HOME/include -I$OMNIORB_HOME/include/omniORB4
g++ -c *.cc -I$OMNIORB_HOME/include -I$OMNIORB_HOME/include/omniORB4
g++ -o Server Server.o EmployeeSK.o WorkSK.o WorkImpl.o EmployeeImpl.o TaskImpl.o TaskSK.o -L$OMNIORB_HOME/lib -lomnithread -lomniORB4
./Server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService

Compile (and run) client files (just copy and paste):

cd EmployeePackage; javac -cp .. *.java
cd OtherPackage; javac -cp .. *.java
cd java; java OtherPackage.Client -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:2809/NameService
```

Here's my working code: http://www9.zippyshare.com/v/46287610/file.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On second thought, I'm not sure my answer was really correct, and stackoverflow won't let me delete my answer once it has been accepted.

Comment: You'd show the correct code, not the bad one. But the answer is fine.

Comment: @Brian Neal: thank you. So should  I better write it this way: `this->thingsToDo[0] = (new TaskImpl("Make backup"))._this();` to avoid memory leak? (Will it be that good as your suggestion with `Servant_var<TaskImpl>` ?)